# Comma? "Dance until dawn at Festive then receive a VIP experience at Escape Spa."

Tags: commas

"Dance until dawn at Festive then receive a VIP experience at Escape Spa."

Should I use a comma before then?

Comment: If you like. It doesn't make much difference here. One function of a comma is to help clarify meaning by splitting up phrases that might otherwise be confusing, but there's no confusion here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems awkward to me without a comma.  But it sounds like something written on a poster...

Dance until dawn

at Festive

then receive

a VIP experience

at Escape Spa

...in which case a comma would be superfluous.